# Map and For loop

Tags: c++, dictionary

I have a problem with my map and loop here. So basically my map is:

```
typedef map <int,string> studentRecord;
studentRecord sRecord;
```

and I put the key and element inside a for loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < sizephys; i++){
    phys.push_back(new physics());
    cout << "\nPlease enter student name:"<<endl;
    getline(cin , namephys);
    cout << "Please enter student id:"<<endl;
    cin >> idphys;
    cin.ignore();
    phys[i]->setNameId(namephys, idphys);
    phys[i]->addCourse(course, mark);
    sRecord[idphys] = namephys;
    }
```

The problem now is I want to use the map to search after the loops end ie like this:

```
int recordSearch;
cout << "\nPlease enter ID key of student to search their record." <<endl;
cin >> recordSearch;
searchDatabase(sRecord,recordSearch);

if (recordSearch == idphys)
{
    phys[i]->printCourseInfo();
}
```

which obviously wont work since phys[i] is outside the loop. Is there any other way to do this? Thank you

```
void searchDatabase(studentRecord &sRecord, int recordSearch)
{
   studentRecord::iterator studRecordIter;
   studRecordIter = sRecord.find(recordSearch);
   if(studRecordIter != sRecord.end()) 
    cout<<"\nFound record for student " <<
    recordSearch << " = "<<
    studRecordIter->second<<endl;
   else
    cout<<"Sorry, record " << recordSearch << 
    " is not in database"<<endl;
}
```

Comment: You know `map` has a function called `find`, right? That's kind of the point of a map.

Comment: Can you show `searchDatabase`?

Comment: @ChrisDrewvoid         
Edited with it.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using a vector (or whatever `pys` is) in the first place?
Anyway, replacing this line:

```
sRecord[idphys] = namephys;
```

with

```
sRecord[idphys] = phys[i];
```

and:

```
typedef map <int,string> studentRecord;
```

with

```
typedef map <int, physic *> studentRecord;
```

Should do the trick.

(Note also that you don't give the type of your vector, so there might be some adjustment)

Comment: And if you use a map from student id to `physics*` like this you can throw away the `phys` vector. I don't see what use it has, assuming the index in the `phys` vector doesn't have some special meaning.

Comment: The vector could for instance be the owner of the `physics` with a `unique_ptr`, and multiple (potentially temporary) maps just being there as convenient index. But yeah this is why I started my answer with "Why are you using [...] in the first place?".